# What is the best method for printing lists nested in dictionaries without brackets in python?

Tags: python

I am teaching myself python, and I was playing around with dictionaries. My goal is to print sentences with correct subject verb agreement w/o brackets around the lists from a dictionary like this.

```
fav_places={
'Kevin':['Aruba','Montenegro'],
'Bob':['Mexico City','Tiwan'],
'Stan':['Kansas']
}
```

This is what I came up with

```
for name, places in fav_places.items():
if len(places)>1:
    print(f"{name}, your favorite places are: {', '.join(places)}.")
else:
    print(f"{name}, your favorite place is {places[0]}")
```

I got this as an output

```
Kevin, your favorite places are: Aruba, Montenegro.
Bob, your favorite places are: Mexico City, Tiwan.
Stan, your favorite place is Kansas
```

Do I have to convert the places list to one string to use it in an f string like this? Is my use of the len function necessary for my goal? Finally, should I even use dictionaries with nested lists for this situation?

Comment: This is a perfectly acceptable solution. You might also want to post your working code on our sister site [codereview.se] for more detailed feedback.

Comment: This is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. As this is working code, you should post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ in order to get advice on ways to improve it.

Comment: "Is my use of the len function necessary for my goal?" I suggest you see what happens when `places` has only one element and you still use the `join()` function.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I don't think this would be acceptable there, either. Read https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @Barmar I don't see anything in that post that indicates this is particular question is a bad fit for Code Review. The code given here works as intended (modulo indentation which I assume is an artifact of posting) and the user is asking for suggestions about how to improve their code with specific concerns. The exact wording and formatting of the question might need to be tweaked, but the heart of the question seems like a good fit for Code Review.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice From https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask: **It's OK to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?"**

Comment: @Barmar I argue that this question is even more specifc than either of those: "Is X considered a best practice?"

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the repetition:

```
def print_favorites(name):
    favorites = fav_places[name]
    print(f"{name}, your favorite place{'s are' if favorites[1:] else ' is'} {', '.join(favorites)}.")
```